# jQuery and JavaScript Math Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I mix jQuery with JavaScript's Math library to access elaborated functions? Since jQuery is valid JS it should be no problem, right?

Comment: Yes you can! If you have any issues. Post them up and we'll help out as much as we can.

Comment: you're right, carry on ...

Comment: Sure you can, good luck.

Comment: See http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif (hint: learn the JavaScript core before using jQuery).

Comment: Rather than library, it might be more appropriate to say `Math` is a built-in JS object. Since jQuery is a library for JS, of course you can use both at the same time.

Comment: Have you ever coded in another language and used an external library? It's the same situation here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery does not kill JavaScript, it's built on top of it and anything you do in JS works within the jQuery framework.

All this to say, that to refer to the `Math` object from jQuery you have to use the complicated and obscure name `Math` :P

```
$(function () {

    alert(Math.round(0.5));

});
```

Comment: `Math.round` does not support a second argument. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) or the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.8.2.15).

Comment: My bad, sorry. For whatever reason I got confused. Corrected.